# array of meta values using WP_User_Query

Tags: wp-query, wp-user-query

I don't see that it is possible when I look at the WordPress documentation but I wanted to confirm. I want to check multiple meta values against one meta key eg:

```
$user_query = new WP_User_Query( array( 'meta_key' => 'user_charname', 'meta_value' => 'squarepants', 'orderby' => 'meta_value_num', 'order' => 'DESC' ));
```

I was hoping I could just use `'meta_value' => array('value1', 'value2')` but that does not work.

I have tried this as pointed out by Jacob (modified) but it gives me what appears to be all results and isn't working as intended.

```
 $args = array(
    'meta_query' => array(
        array(
            'key'     => 'user_charname',
            'value'   => array('spongebob', 'mickey'),
            'compare' => '='
        )
    )
 );
$user_query = new WP_User_Query( $args );
```

Comment: Have you read https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_user_query/#custom-field-parameters?

Comment: @JacobPeattie, thank you for that. I took a look and did try to use it but perhaps my implementation is incorrect as it doesn't work as intended.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just wanted to know if it's possible, then yes **it is possible**.

But the problem as I could see it from your edited question, is that you set the `compare` to `=` which should instead be `IN`.

However, you didn't actually have to set it because when you supply an array of values, the operator will default to `IN`.

So the correct code would be:

```php
'meta_query' => array(
    array(
        'key'     => 'user_charname',
        'value'   => array('spongebob', 'mickey'),
        'compare' => 'IN' // use IN
    )
)
```

Comment: Ahhhh. Don't you just love it when something is staring you in the face and you still can't see it! Thank you!

Comment: You're welcome :)